# Image is not getting added to the scene -Phaser 3.5

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, game-development

I am trying to learn phaser js but have been stuck on figuring out why my background images are not displaying to the scene. I have tried moving the image file to different locations and also tried doing function declarations instead of methods everything with the same result. Thank you in advance for any guidance you may be able to provide! Btw I am using parcel-bundler Code & screenshot

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMBEg.png)

First is main.js

```js
import Phaser, { Physics } from "phaser"
import { TitleScene } from "./scenes"

const GameConfig = {
  width: 800,
  height: 500,
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  physics: {
    default: "arcade",
    arcade: {
      gravity: {
        y: 0,
      },
    },
  },
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(GameConfig);

game.scene.add("title", TitleScene);

game.scene.start("title");
```

This is my scenes.js files:

```js
import Phaser, { Textures } from "phaser"

export class TitleScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    preload() {
        this.load.image("sky", "sky.png");
    }

    create() {
       this.add.image(400, 250, "sky");
       const titleText = this.add.text(400, 250, "Hello World!");
       titleText.setOrigin(0.5,0.5);
     //this.add.arc(400, 250, 128, 0, 360, false, 0xff0000);
        
    }
};

export class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    preload() {

    }

    create() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having a similar issue I was able to fix 2 ways 1 by importing the image directly like this: `import bg0 from "./assets/bg0.png"` or by using require() as such:  `this.load.image("bg0", require("./assets/bg0.png"))` I suspect these are needed either because of some macos setting issue or a parcel-bundler issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to adjust the path that is supplied for the image url relative to `scenes.js`

For example,

```js
// __rootDir__/js/scenes.js
import Phaser from 'phaser'

export class TitleScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  preload() {
    this.load.image("sky", "../images/sky.jpg") // path relative to scenes.js
  }

  create() {
    const image = this.add.image(200, 200, "sky")
    image.setScale(1.0)

    const titleText = this.add.text(200, 200, "Hello World!")
    titleText.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5)
  }
}

export class GameScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  preload() {}
  create() {}
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-66878947-qhevi?file=/js/scenes.js

https://phaser.io/examples/v2/basics/01-load-an-image

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was helpful in finding out the issue. I got it working by importing the image directly into scenes.js like this: import sky from "./sky.png" could be macOS permissions issue maybe.